# How do I intersect a point with a shape?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I have a table in Postgresql / PostGIS containing county geometries. This table was created by importing a shapefile. I verified the geometry was imported successfully by importing the table into QGIS to view the polygon positions and ensure everything was drawing correctly. So, now I have geometry in a table.

Now, I want to write a SQL query to return the polygon that a points intersects. For example, given a lat/lon of 35, 80 it should return the row for the county that contains the point at 35, 80.

The geometry is in the database with SRID EPSG:2810, "NAD83(HARN) / Minnesota North". The point is in WGS84 - typical coordinates taken from a GPS receiver.

How do I select the row that the point intersects with? The geometry in the GEOM column of type geometry.

Here's a query I started but it doesn't return any rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM county
WHERE ST_Intersects(
        geom,
        ST_GeometryFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(47.000000 -91.000000)')
        );
```

Comment: It's not surprising that a search one degree below the South Pole doesn't return any data, even if that data was in GCS_WGS_1984 (which it isn't).  It may help if you stop thinking "lat/lon" and start thinking "lon,lat".  But you'll also need to do NADCON and reprojection (a search on "ST_Transform" would be appropriate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Vince pointed out:

```
SELECT *
FROM county
WHERE ST_Intersects(
        geom,
        ST_Transform(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-91.0 47.0)', 4326), 2810)
        );
```

You can also use [ST_MakePoint()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) if that would be easier with your source than constructing the WKT.

Comment: There was some fine print in the [man page](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) on how to use PROJ.4 options for NADCON to convert the WGS84 to NAD83 during transform.